# Is there a way to have a background process checking a website while still using your program?

Tags: python, asynchronous, twitter, tweepy

I am writing a twitter bot that is controlled using a GUI and I want to automatically check a websites new page for updates and if it isn't a duplicate then tweet it. I've got the system for checking the website for changes and only tweeting if it isn't a duplicate. But I'm looking for a way to have a background process where this code would be constantly running while the GUI is still be used, e.g. I'm replying to tweets using the program and in the background the bot is tweeting updates. I was thinking of async but I can't seem to get it to work in this context, any ideas?

Comment: You could start a new thread using `threading` if you aren't doing a lot of calculations, or a new process using `subprocess` or `multiprocessing`. Asyncio will have the problem of competing for CPU-time with the GUI thread.

Comment: threading worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def function_for_the_background_task():
   while True:
       do_something

update_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_for_the_background_task)
update_thread.start()


rest of program
```

Comment: Keep in mind though, `threading` should only be used if the background task is almost entirely waiting on IO. If you're doing any "work", the GIL will make it so this will likely still lag the GUI. You'll need a separate process to do work in the background.

Comment: Is there an alternative to threading more designed for this? I feel as though running two processes at the same is a common thing in programming.

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module contains both thread and process pools, and also a `Process` constructor that works the same as `Thread`, but runs the target in another process.

Comment: Asyncio is also meant for running multiple IO waits on a single thread, but it has a bit of a learning curve, and requires its own thread.

Comment: I was looking into using it but the UI I'm using doesn't work too well with it as I would need the task to be constantly running in the background, essentially separate from the GUI but still connected to the program and the UI software has a typical .go() so anything after that isn't looked at.